# I am getting the wrong output when trying post-increment operation on a pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, post-increment, pre-increment

I am testing out pre- and post-increment on an array using pointer. I use the pointers `p` and `q` to access the elements of the array but the issue stems from the last result on pointer `p`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int a[] = {10, 11, -1, 56, 67, 5, 4};
        int *p, *q;
        p = a;
        q = &a[0] + 3;
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", (*p)++, (*p)++, *(++p));
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        printf("%d\n", (*p)++);
        printf("%d\n", (*p)++);
        q--;
        printf("%d\n", (*(q + 2))--);
        printf("%d\n", *(p + 2) - 2);
        printf("%d\n", *(p++ - 2) - 1);
}
```

This is the output I get, I made the wrong output I am having bold:

```
12, 11, 11
13
13
14
67
54
**22025**
```

I am supposed to get the result 0 printed on the last `printf` statement in the code when I run it since after the previous lines of code `p` should be on the fourth element i.e. `a[3]` on the array, if `p` increments to `a[4]` then goes backward twice to `a[2]` (from the expression `p++ - 2`) then de-referenced and 1 is subtracted from the value, the final value should be 0 but I get a garbage value every time I run it. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong or why I am getting such value?

Comment: Comment your code stating what you believe each line is doing to each array element. This way you will explain it to yourself and to us, the readers.

Comment: Don't use multiple auto-increments on the same value in one argument list. The order of operation is not specified between the arguments, so this causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The value of `p++ - 2` is `p - 2`, since you're using post-increment. Since `p == &a[1]`, this accesses before the beginning of the array.

Comment: **after the previous lines of code p should be on the fourth element i.e. a[3]**. Why do you think that? The previous line didn't reassign `p`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the tip.
@Barmar. It is an exercise from a course to better help students understand pre and post-increment, and your comment I think that is where I have it wrong, why is it `p` not reassigned when the output looks like it is `a[3] - 2` i.e. 54

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain what I am doing wrong or why I am getting such value?

Yes.

> if `p` increments to `a[4]` [...]

But `p` *does not* get incremented to point to `a[4]`.  The value of `p` is incremented only twice during the whole program.  Once here:

> ```
>         printf("%d, %d, %d\n", (*p)++, (*p)++, *(++p));
> ```

, with the `++p`, and once here:

> ```
>         printf("%d\n", *(p++ - 2) - 1);
> ```

, with the `p++`.

You also have several appearances of `(*p)++`, but, as the parentheses direct, the object that is incremented in those cases is the one to which `p` *points*, not `p` itself.  You have a `p + 2`, too, but that does not modify anything.

However, when the expression `*(p++ - 2) - 1` is evaluated, only one of those increments has yet been applied, and although `p++` performs another increment, it *evaluates to* the value of `p` prior to that increment, which points to `a[1]`.  Under those circumstances, `p++ - 2` has undefined behavior on account of attempting to compute an address outside the bounds of array `a`, on which `p` is based.

And as long as we're on UB, note well that this ...

> ```
>         printf("%d, %d, %d\n", (*p)++, (*p)++, *(++p));
> ```

... also has UB.  In this case, it's because the side effect of `++p` on the value of `p` is unsequenced with the evaluations of `p` in the two appearances of `(*p)++`, *and* because the side effects of those two appearances of `(*p)++` are unsequenced relative to each other (either one of those causes would have been sufficient, so extra credit for you!).  Surprising results are possible; inconsistent results are likely from implementation to implementation, and in principle, *anything* within the computer's ability could happen.

Comment: Thanks so much for breaking it down, can you explain why `p + 2` does nothing in the second to the last statement, as this is why i expected it to increment to `a[3]` but from your statement you say it does nothing

Comment: @Monarch, I said `p + 2` does not *modify* anything, not that it does not *do* anything.  It computes a result, which in turn is used as an operand in another operation, but the result of the `p + 2` is not itself stored in `p` or any other object.  I'm not sure why you would expect otherwise.  Would you think that if `p` were an `int` or a `double` instead of a pointer?

Comment: ohhhhh I get it now, I can't believe I made such a silly error in reasoning, I got it now,  thanks for your patience with me